# tracking remote repository from another remote in git

Tags: git, repository, tracking

Gosh, there are so many answered questions but i'm not sure about any of them.

**Prerequisites:**

1. My project has main repository on github.
2. My project has repository on sourceforge as well

**Expected results:**

1. While developing i am pushing to my github repository (simple git push).
2. Someone is cloning sourceforge repo (simple git clone).
3. Someone is pushing his changes to sourceforge repo (simple git
   push).
4. Both, sourceforge and github are still in sync.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to configure something like this?
2. I don't need backup. It would be good if sourceforge wouldn't have to fetch/send any data from/to github (so they wouldn't have to waste resources). So, generally - sourceforge should provide some kind of link to github repository, and this link should be automatically accessed at initial git clone .

Sorry, i'm adding a new question on this topic but i'm too confused what to use, if it will work, and most importantly - if it wont make a mess in my repo. I expect this would be something like remote tracking repo :)

Comment: Just close the repository on SourceForge or put just one file into it which states where the main repository can be fetched. It's easier and less error prone than keeping two repositories in sync and merging changes between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a good way to do this, no. Perhaps just provide a link to Github from your project's Sourceforge page instead?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it can't be automated is that you have a potential to introduce conflicts that only a human can resolve.  If you really want to keep them in sync a human will have to pull from both, resolve any conflicts, and then push to both.  Alternately, you could make one of the repositories read-only, so other people can pull from it, but only one person can push, which eliminates the potential for conflict.  However, unless you have a really good reason for keeping it duplicated, I would recommend closing one of the accounts.

Comment: I didn't had in mind that git should automatically merge branches, but there should be one repository, and one link - when someone tries push to link, it should be forwarded (or just pushed to main repo) instead. But thank you guys for answers, i thought it's possible.